# Set a sun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout for a single thread only?

Tags: java, spring, rmi

We have an RMI call that needs to finish or fail within a couple of seconds. You can modify the `Socket` used during the call itself (including the connect and read timeouts), but the `Naming.lookup` call seems to use its own parameters.

Reducing `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout` fixes the problem, but I'd really like to do it in a way that does not affect the entire VM. Can you set the property as a thread local?

The property and other RMI properties are documented at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html

Comment: The handshake timeout doesn't cover the etire call, only the initial protocol exchange, so setting it can't 'fix the problem'. There is an undocumented response timeout property, but it can't be set per thread. Naming.lookup() doesn't do anything special in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found an ugly way to accomplish this. The `lookup` is performed using a `Socket` from a `RMIClientSocketFactory` which you can pass. The factory returns a `Socket` with your configuration.

Unfortunately, that doesn't do you a whole lot of good, since the `TCPChannel` class used in RMI overwrites some of your configuration, including calling `Socket.setSoTimeout(..)` with the value of `handshakeTimeout`.

However, nothing is stopping you from modifying the factory to return a sub-class of `Socket` which does not permit chaning `soTimeout` (ie. by overwriting `setSoTimeout` to do nothing).

Having the source available for the `TCPChannel` class turned out to be very useful: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/rmi/sun/rmi/transport/tcp/TCPChannel.java.htm